# Probability of having $1$ common element in two random $\frac{n}{2}$-element subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Two people each choose, independently and randomly, a set of $11$ numbers from $\{1,2,\dots,22\}$. What is the probability of them having exactly $1$ common number?

What if I wish to generalise this to $k$ common numbers?

Attempt:
I started with smaller data set to get a gist of it.

If there were only $6$ numbers to choose from i.e. $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, and the two people are choosing $3$ each, then there are a total of $C(6,3)=20$ triplets.

There are then $C(20,2)/2= 95$ pairs of triplets as sample space.

For exactly one common element, it could be any, so $6$ choices.

$C(5,2)$ choices left for person A and $C(3,2)$ choices for person B so that no other element is common.
So probability= $\frac{6\times 10\times 3}{2\times95} =90/95=18/19$
But it intuitively seems a bit high.

I don't have the answer to this as it is just a question I thought of.
Please correct my approach if incorrect somewhere. And guide further.

Comment: You need to include your effort in the post

Comment: Without loss of generality, you can assume the first person chose the numbers $1$ through $11$.  That should help you figure out how to solve this.  Yes, please **edit your question** to explain your efforts.  Questions that show no evidence of an independent attempt to reach a solution usually are not well received here.  They usually are quickly downvoted and closed.

Comment: You're asking about a probability without having described any situation involving randomness. I suspect you forgot to add the premise that the people choose the numbers randomly uniformly from among all eleven-element subsets?

Comment: I have included my attempt now. Commenting here as I am not sure if others would receive a notification of the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $2n$ total numbers, and each person chooses $n$. We would like the each person to have $n-1$ distinct numbers and $1$ number in common, totaling to $2n -1$ numbers chosen. First, lets choose the number the have in common, there are $2n \choose 1$ total ways to do this. Then, we want to choose the other $n-1$ numbers for the first person, of which there are $2n -1 \choose n - 1$ total ways to do this. Then, for each way we can choose them we need to choose the other persons $n-1$ numbers, leading to $n \choose n-1$ total ways. In total we have:
$${2n \choose 1} {2n-1 \choose n -1} {n \choose n-1}$$ Good ways to choose the numbers. Out of a total of ${2n \choose n}^2$ total ways. Hence the generalized form for $2n$ numbers is:

$$\frac{{2n \choose 1} {2n-1 \choose n -1} {n \choose n-1}}{{2n \choose n}^2}$$ And when $n=11$ the answer comes out to $0.00017$ from mathematica.

Comment: Thank you for the reply sir. It's easy to understand. But can I use the same strategy if I wish to find the probability of having exactly k common elements? Would PIE be used?

Comment: Without thinking too hard, I believe it’s the same concept just replace $1$ with $k$.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve the problem by counting the cases.

As noticed, we can assume that first person chooses $11$ elements then we can count on the second person.

The second person has $22 \choose 11$ possible choices and, for the favourable cases, has ${11 \choose 10}=11$ choices for the different $10$ elements and $11$ choices for the common element, that is a probability

$$\frac{11\cdot 11}{22 \choose 11}$$